# How can I check the following inequality?

Tags: calculus, integration, sobolev-spaces

Let $n \ge 3 $, $1/2 < s \le 1$, then $\forall v \in H^s(B(0,1))$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_{|\omega|=1} |v(w)|^2 dw \lesssim \left( \int_{B(0,1)} \frac{|v(x)|^2}{|x|^{2s}}+\Big||D|^sv(x)\Big|^2 \right)dx.
\end{equation}

Comment: What is D? (More characters)

Comment: @martycohenma D is differential operator. More precisely, $|D|^s f$ can be defined by the Fourier inversion of $|\xi|^s \hat{f}(xi)$